# Query div animations

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I would like to know how to animate an entire div towards the top of the page, now it seems pretty simple, but even after loads of research, i can't figure out what I've done wrong, it simply won't work so here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#q').bind('webkitspeechchange',function()
    {
        $(this).parent('form').submit();
    });
});
function check()
{
    var searchtext = document.getElementById("q").value;
    if(searchtext=='')
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true; 
    }
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#q").focus();
});



$("#button").click( function() {             
    $("#content").animate({
        top: 0
    },1000)
});



</script>
```

I'm trying to animate #content to the top, for reference here is the full page: http://dev.thiv.net/

I'm really stuck, any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is present before the element in question. You need to encase that in **DOM Ready Handler** for the event to be bound properly

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#q').bind('webkitspeechchange', function () {
            $(this).parent('form').submit();
        });

        $("#q").focus();
        $("#button").click(function () {
            $("#content").animate({
                top: 0
            }, 1000)
        }); 
    });

    function check() {
        var searchtext = document.getElementById("q").value;
        if (searchtext == '') {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Also you can encase all the code inside a single `ready` handler instead of placing it under multiple instances. Also it's a better idea to place the script tag just before the closing tag of the body for better performance.

And looks like your button is inside the form . So you would need to prevent the default action of the form if you want it to work. Remove the `onsubmit` event for the form and submit the form using jQuery.

```
$("#button").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#content").animate({
        top: 0
     }, 1000);

    var check = check();
    if(check) {
       $('form').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this works really well, now the page can move in style

Comment: @Connor.. Glad to have helped :)

Comment: hey, how can i make it animate only if #q has something in it, basically checking if its empty before allowing it to animate and return false or nothing if it is empty

Comment: Just check for this condition `if($('#q').val()) { // Animate }`